# Debugging js errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, debugging

Im debugging erros http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home and im getting those erros while they work fine on my website .

Im debugging a js file . So all those under are in js file.

Should i replace them or how can i fix them ?

1

> JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. String continuations are not supported in this language mode. //

```
 $("#new_data").after('<div class="cont_price_op">'+dat.price_ops[i]+'</div>')
                                                                    ^
```

2

> JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. String continuations are not supported in this language mode

```
  $("#new_data").after('<div class="cont_price_op">'+dat.price_ops[i]+'</div>')
                        ^
```

3

> JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. String continuations are not supported in this language mode

```
   if(dat.company_pers ==1){ msg =' <div class="wish...
                                   ^
```